# C : x to the power n using repeated squaring without recursive function

Tags: c

here is my code it calculate 2 raised to the  power 16

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    long int x=2;
    int n=16;
    int k=log(n)/log(2);
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        x=x*x;
    }
    printf("%d",x);
    printf("\n%d",k);
}
```

i want to calculate this when the power of x i.e. n is not the power of 2. for eg. say n=19,n=43 etc

Comment: There is no recursion in the example you've shown.

Comment: @devnull Which was apparently also the requirement.

Comment: Do you understand math behind it? It is impossible. Also recursion has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Lundin Exactly.  As such it's extremely unclear what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you are looking for [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) which goes like this:

```
unsigned int intpow(unsigned int base, unsigned int exponent)
{
    unsigned int result = 1;
    while (exponent > 0)
    {
        while ((exponent & 1) == 0)
        {
            exponent /= 2;
            base *= base;
        }
        exponent--;
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is actualy an efficient way of doing what i was looking for. it took .029 s while my code took .067 s

Answer (score 1):

To make the code work for other powers make these changes, multiply by to get the extra power.

```
int main()
{
int i;
long int x=2;
int n=7;
int k=log(n)/log(2);
int y,z;
y=n-pow(2,k);
z=1;
for(i=0;i<y;i++)
{
    z*=x;
}
for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
{
 x=x*x;
 }
 x=x*z;
printf("%d",x);
printf("\n%d",k);
}
```

Comment: You used `pow` which somewhat defeats the purpose of the exercise methinks