# How to round up a floating variable in c upto 2/3/4....n digits precision without using <math.h> and printf(".n%f")

Tags: c

float f = 2.8386483,g ;

//Suppose I am having f = 2.8386483..... I want to store k = 2.8.... to n positions where n=a natural //number

//e.g. g= 2.83 to 2 decimal precision/n=2
    //   g = 2.838 to 3 decimal precision/n=3

Comment: How do you want 2.8386483 to be 'rounded' to one decimal place? An IEEE float cannot represent 2.8 precisely.  I think you'll need to either use a data type other than `float`, or you'll need to be content with performing the rounding at display time.

Comment: okay consider upto 2 places of precision to be minimum

Comment: Are you concerned how number looks when displayed, or how it is stored?  Two completely different things.

Comment: @user3565835: setting a minimum number of digits doesn't solve the problem of numbers that are unable to be represented precisely.

Comment: Given `float f = 2.8386483`, are you sure you want 3 decimal precision to be `2.838` and not `2.839`?

Comment: If you try to store `2.83` (or `2.8300000000`) in a `float` object, the actual value stored will likely be `2.8299999237060546875`. Rounding makes sense when you *display* a value. Trying to store a round value in a floating-point object is rarely useful.

Comment: @KeithThompson - _the actual value stored will likely be `2.8299999237060546875`_  for a `float` or for a `double`?

Comment: @user3565835 - Perhaps your question should be restated:  _Given that I cannot use `math.h` functions, or use formatting such as `".n%f"`, is there a way to PRESENT a floating point number with ONLY a specified precision, (regardless of how it is stored).  For example if I have 1.2345678. and want to DISPLAY 1.234, how would I do that?_.  ***I ask this rhetorically*** because in your original post, you clearly say:  _I want to STORE k=..._

Answer (score 2):

Without using math.h, or printf(“.n%f”), the other answer will work for you.

But regarding your phrase *I want to store k = 2.8.... to n positions*.  It may be interesting to you that this has less to do with rounding than it has to do with `type`, and how much memory is required to store each type.

`float`, `double` and `long double` require differing amounts of memory to ***store*** the precision (numbers to the right of ".") required by the type, regardless of how you format them for ***display***.   That is:

***A displayed*** representation of a `float` may look like `2.83`
***while in memory***, a `float` will contain memory sufficient to 7 digits precision `2.8368361` (on 32 bit system)
***And for a*** type `double` representation of the same number might stored as `2.836836100000001`.

***Again***, *the way a number has little to do with how it is stored.*

***Edit:*** (Rounding a float to n decimal places)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>//I did not realized that this header INCLUDEs math.h, oops
int main(void)
{
    int p;

    float a,c;

    printf("Enter the floating point value:-");

    scanf("%f",&a);

    printf("Enter the precision value:-");

    scanf("%d",&p);

    if(a>0)
    {
        c=((int)(a*pow(10,p)+0.5)/(pow(10,p)));
        printf("Value Rounding Off:-%f",c);
    }

    else

    {
        c=((int)(a*pow(10,p)+0.5)/(pow(10,p)));
        printf("Value Rounding Off:-%f",c);
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

From ***[HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-function-to-round-floating-point-numbers/)*** (thanks to H. Gupta)

Comment: Nothing is working please write a valid c program and yield the output !

Comment: I am not sure what you want because you never answer my question above:  _Are you concerned how number looks when displayed, or how it is stored?_  But see my edit for a working code example of how to round a float number to n places...

Comment: I told you <math.h> no to use

Comment: See ***[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23254545/645128)*** answer, he has what you want without using math.h.  I would also think it is a good candidate for an upclick it and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have *n* digits, then you can first start with multiplying your number f with 10^n. After that you can turn it into an integer so that the rest of the decimals "disappear" - turn it again into an float and divide by 10^n

However, remember to check for if the number needs to be rounded up or down :)

- 2 places = 10^2
- 2.836836 * 10^2 = 283.6836
- rounding rules: add 0.5 to the number
- 283.6836 + 0.5 = 284.1836
- (int) 284.1836 = 284
- 284 * 1.0 / 10^2 = 2.84

=>

float f = 10^2 * f + 0.5

int newint = (int) f f = newint * 1.0 / 10^2

Comment: suppose my no. is 2.836836.... I want to round it up to 2 places how to do using c

Comment: i modified my answer because this comment is too messy. but if you want to round your number n places instead of 2, you just use 10^n instead of 10^2

Comment: rounding up 2 places in this case equates to 4 numbers after the decimal place.  requires 10^4 resulting in 28368.36.  Rounding rules -> 3<5, so drop it. divide results in 2.8368.

Comment: sorry i did not get what you mean? surely rounding up to 2 places means that you want to achieve two numbers after the "dot"

Comment: #include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
float output1 ;
void main()
{
   // f = 1.8 * c + 32  ;
   float f ,c=39,tmp ;
   int g,g1 ;
   fflush(stdin) ;
    clrscr() ;
   f = 1.8*c+32   ;
    f= (f*100)+0.5 ;
      g= (int)f ;
      f  = g*(1/100);
      printf("%f",f);
      getch() ;




}

Comment: the above C code is yielding 0.00000/NAN instead of the desired result

Comment: @user3565835 - the code you posted has errors.  Once fixed, the result is `0.000000`

Comment: @SaraSeppola - my mistake.  I read it as ***round up two places***, when I _should have read_ ***round it up to two places***.  You are correct.

Comment: @ryyker please write a valid c program to implement the same

Answer (score 1):

Scale `x` and then round.  Make sure to deal with negative numbers correctly if rounding to nearest.

Thanks to @David Heffernan [C : x to the power n using repeated squaring without recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079443/c-x-to-the-power-n-using-repeated-squaring-without-recursive-function)

```
float pow10f(unsigned exponent) {
  float base = 10.0;
  float result = 1.0;
  while (exponent > 0) {
    while ((exponent & 1) == 0) {
      exponent /= 2;
      base *= base;
    }
    exponent--;
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
}

float RoundToNPlaces(float x, unsigned n) {
  if (x < 0.0) {
    return -RoundToNPlaces(-x, n);
  }
  float scale = pow10f(n);  // fix per @Michael Burr
  x *= scale;
  uintmax_t u = (uintmax_t) (x + 0.5);  // Add 0.5 if rounding to nearest.
  x = (float) u;
  x /= scale;
  return x;
}
```

Does have a range limit though but likely wider than `int`.

---

[Edit] per @Michael Burr comment

`(int) (RoundToNPlaces( 2.8386483, 2) * 100)` --> `283` rather than the expected 284.  What happened though, is correct.  Rounded to 2 places the result of `2.8386483` is mathematically `2.84` but is not representable with typical `float`.  The 2 closest `float` to `2.84` are

```
2.8399999141693115234375000  
2.8400001525878906250000000
```

and `RoundToNPlaces( 2.8386483, 2)` resulted in the *closer* one: `2.8399999141693115234375`.

Now performing `(int) (2.8399999141693115234375f * 100)` --> `(int) 283.99999141693115234375f` --> `283`.

This exhibits the necessary compromise to the OP's original goal, finding 2.8386483f rounded to 2 decimal places does not typically lead to an *exact* answer.  Hence subsequent operations like `* 100` and then `int` conversion lead to unexpected results, not because the best answer was not found in the round to 2 decimal places step, but because the best answer still will not exhibit all the properties of the mathematical exact answer.

Comment: Now its all just for fun.  +1

Comment: And here's what I get for `(int) (RoundToNPlaces( 2.8386483, 2) * 100)`: 283.  I would expect 284 if the rounding worked precisely. Also I had to fix-up the `pow10f()` call in `RoundToNPlaces()` to compile.