# How can my own printf do the same round as the original one?

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to make my own `printf` and I have a problem with the `"%f"` option, precisely with rounding. When I try to prints this test :

```
print("Real : %.8f\n",1685.2622);
```

The original one gave : `1685.26220000` and mine gave : `1685.26220704`.

I don't know how to fix it ...

Here is my code below :

```
#include "../includes/ft_printf.h"
#include <stdarg.h>

void ft_reverse_str(char *str, int len) {
  int i;
  int j;
  int tmp;

  i = 0;
  j = len - 1;
  while (i < j) {
    tmp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = tmp;
    i++;
    j--;
  }
}

int convert_int_to_str(int int_part, char *ret_str, int precision) {
  int i;

  i = 0;
  while (int_part) {
    int_part += 0.5;
    ret_str[i++] = (int_part % 10) + '0';
    int_part = int_part / 10;
  }
  while (i < precision)
    ret_str[i++] = '0';
  ft_reverse_str(ret_str, i);
  ret_str[i] = '\0';
  return (i);
}

void float_itoa(float nbr, char *ret_str, int precision) {
  int int_part;
  float float_part;
  int i;
  int_part = (int) nbr;
  float_part = nbr - (float) int_part;
  i = convert_int_to_str(int_part, ret_str, 0);
  if (precision != 0) {
    ret_str[i] = '.';
    i++;
    float_part = float_part * ft_pow(10, precision);
    convert_int_to_str((int) float_part, ret_str + i, precision);
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to use `double` rather than `float` internally, because all `float` arguments are promoted to `double` anyway ? (Also note that your `1685.2622` argument that you are using for testing is a literal `double`.)

Comment: In the most commonly used format for `float`, `1865.2622f` in source text becomes 1865.26220703125 in `float`. This means your implementation is doing a better job in this case, which suggests the `printf` you are using is low quality. Which `printf` is it? Microsoft? Apple? GNU? Somebody else? What version? Do you want to duplicate that `printf` exactly, or do you want to do a high-quality job?

Comment: Conversion of binary floating-point to decimal is complicated. It is not easy to do a good job (one that gets rounding correct and is efficient).

Comment: c literals are double by default. Your value comes out to 1685.26220000 as a double. But when you cast to float it's turned into 1685.26220703125. Add an `f` on the end to force it to float literal.

Comment: `int_part += 0.5;` is the same as `int_part += 0` same as `(void) int_part;` - as if the code was not there.

Comment: saouas, What would you like code to do with `int_part = (int)nbr;`  when `nbr` is outside the `int` range?

Comment: @BurnsBA Note: C calls 1685.26220000 a _constant_, not a _literal_.  C does have _literals_ such as _string literal_ which can have their address taken.  unlike the address of 1685.26220000.

Comment: @chux oh yes, of course, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 major problems:

- Code is using `float` math in trying to print a `double` that exceeds the precision of `float`.  `1685.2622` as a `float` typically encodes in [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) exactly as 1685.26220703125. So an output of `1685.26220704` is not so bad.

Code using `double`

```
void double_itoa(double nbr, char *ret_str, int precision) {
  int int_part;
  double double_part;
  int i;
  int_part = (int) nbr;
  double_part = nbr - (double) int_part;
  i = convert_int_to_str(int_part, ret_str, 0);
  if (precision != 0) {
    ret_str[i] = '.';
    i++;
    double_part = double_part * pow(10, precision);
    convert_int_to_str(round(double_part), ret_str + i, precision);
  }
}
```

- Truncation rather than rounding.

`(int) float_part` lops off the fraction.  A better approach would round as incorporated above `round(double_part)`.  To create a good round function without `<math.h>` has subtle pitfalls versus the *usual* `(int) (x + 0.5)`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23254545/2410359) may help.

Example:

```
int main() {
  char s[100];
  float_itoa(1685.2622, s, 8);
  puts(s);
  double_itoa(1685.2622, s, 8);
  puts(s);
}
```

Output

```
1685.26220704
1685.26220000
```

---

Code has other weaknesses such as  using `(int) some_floating_point_value` is prone to significant failure should the FP value lie outside the `int` range.

Comment: Thank's you very much for your answer !! :) , i really understand now why it doesn't work.