# How to calculate a power of a number with O(log n) complexity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

This is for pure understanding, but i have a code thats basically O(n), but i am unable to decipher how to change it to Olog(n), and each time i use recursion i get nlog(n) complexity.

```
def power(n,p):
    val = []
    for i in range(p):
        val.append(n)
    res = val
    n = 1
    for x in res:
        n*= x
    return n
print(power(2,8)) # returns 256
```

what i need is a code that does the exact same as this above code but it basically does it in Olog(n) as opposed to O(n)

Comment: essentially i want to understand how to divide something that cumulatively adding all the time.

Comment: Notice that you can raise a number to the power of 8 by squaring it three times.

Comment: See an implementation in C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23079728/509868)

Comment: Why do you construct a constant list `val` that consists of the same value repeated `p` times?  It makes no sense.

Comment: @TomKarzes I did it in hopes of finding a way to combine from within the list. But i kept failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code implements `power()` with complexity **O(log(n))**:

```
def power(x, y): 
    if y==0: 
        return 1
    n = power(x, y // 2)  
    if y % 2 == 0: 
        return n * n 
    else: 
        if y > 0: 
            return x * n * n 
        else: 
            return (n * n) / x
```